# Matching a specific string between foward slash or # using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, uri, string-matching, trailing-slash

I'm trying to make this regex:

```
([?=section\/en\/]*)([^\/#]*)
```

For these examples:

```
https://www.test.com/en/string-to-get#cid=4949
https://www.test.com/en/section/string-to-get/page&2#cid=4949
https://www.test.com/en/section/string-to-get#cid=4949
```

[current regex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWZSU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```
(?<=section\/)([^\/#]*)
```

Or, just

```
section\/([^\/#]*)
```

and grab Group 1 value.

Here,

- `(?<=section\/)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location immediately preceded with `section/` substring
- `([^\/#]*)` - Capturing group 1: zero or more chars other than `/` and `#`.

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/FlK1dD/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/FlK1dD/2).

Depending on whether or not regex delimiters are required and if they are not `/`s you may use an unescaped `/`, `(?<=section/)([^/#]*)` and `section/([^/#]*)`.

Comment: Please view my edit, i need this regex to work for three examples. I'm trying to make something like this ([?=section\/en\/]*)([^\/#]*)

Comment: @JuanManuel No idea what your requirements are. `const match = text.match(/(?<=section\/)[^\/#]*|[^\/#?]+(?=[?#])/); console.log( match?.[0] );` might work.

Comment: i need to match three examples https://regex101.com/r/vsFON4/1 in one regex

Comment: @JuanManuel You match them exactly as I showed in the above comment. Do not use regex101.com.